# Postgres ERROR: could not seek to end of file global/1262: Permission denied

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm new to PostgreSQL.

I installed PostgreSQL 12 on the windows 10 desktop machine and trying to access it using pgAdmin 4.

I am successfully connecting to the database but when trying to open Schemas, frequently getting below error:

**ERROR: could not seek to end of file global/1262: Permission denied**

Refer :

[image]

Don't understand what is issue

Comment: Try asking at https://serverfault.com/ or similar fora. This site is for programming related questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed PostgreSQL successfully but there is a problem on the drive on which database directory installed. Changing the drive of my current database directory by following the below steps worked for me.

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Change_the_default_PGDATA_directory_on_Windows

Answer (score 0):

You did not install PostgreSQL successfully, since you are missing important system tables.

Stop the server, delete the database directory and run [`initdb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html) again to create a new, healthy database directory.

Comment: How to delete database directory and where to run initdb command?

Comment: I have added a link to `initdb`, you run it from `cmd.exe` on Windows. Don't ask me where `initdb` is, it is where you installed it. To delete the database directory, either use Windows explorer or `rmdir /s` in `cmd.exe`. Don't ask me where the data directory is, it is where you specified it during the installation process.